# For the Miller-Rabin primality test why must the witnesses be chosen randomly?

Tags: number-theory, primality-test

Why do the witnesses in the Miller_rabin primality test have to be chosen randomly?  Wouldn't just a deterministic set of witnesses, say starting with 1 and 100 or 1000, etc. apart work just as well?

Comment: For every finite collection of bases , there are infinite many composites passing the Miller-Rabin test using the chosen bases. For numbers without a special form , the Miller Rabin test for , say , the prime bases upto $19$ is usually more then sufficient.

Comment: Any time you allow a pattern in statistical data, you risk that some unknown effect may either support that pattern, causing your probabilities to be too high, or work against that pattern, causing your probabilities to be too low.